# how to determine if how many elements < last element in array

Tags: c++, arrays

I am new to programming and I would like some assistance with something I'm trying to solve. I want to have an array that the user can input the values an then determine how many of those values are less than the last element in the array... Below is what i have tried but I think I have a problem with the comparison part

Below i have initialized the array to be strictly 7 elements. All user inputted. I loop through all of the elements but my comparison seems to be off. i tried doing something like `userVals[i] < userVals[i -1]` but this doesn't seem to work. Any Suggestions??

```
int main(){
  const int numOfElements = 7;
  char userVals[numOfElements];
  int counter = 0;

  cout << "Enter " << numOfElements << " integer values"<<endl;

  for( int i = 0; i < numOfElements; ++i){
    cout << "value ";
    cin >> userVals[i];
  }
  for( int i = 0; i < numOfElements; ++i){
    if (userVals[0] < userVals[6]){
      counter++;
    }
  }
  cout << counter;
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Seems like you should change `if (userVals[0] < userVals[6])` to `if (userVals[i] < userVals[6])`

Comment: That was a simple fix thank you! One more question if i may add... i try to put the number 10 as a value but it takes it as 2 values?? Any fix for this?

Comment: You must declare userval as an array of int, not char.

Comment: Using `std::vector<char> v` instead of `char userVals[numOfElements]`, you can do `char last_el = v.back(); std::sort(v.begin(), v.end()); return std::distance(v.begin(), std::lower_bound(v.begin(), v.end(), last_el)));`

Comment: Thanks @Eugene didn't catch that i was modifying another piece of code that accepted characters instead of integers. Copy and paste problems

Comment: @Kosta are you deriding overuse of STL algorithms?

Comment: @Kosta: `O(n log n)` instead of `O(n)` from OP, `std::count_if` seems more appropriate.

Comment: @Jarod42 fair but tbh it’s nice to have a sorted array, and it’s O(1) for 7 elements anyway :)